# python: windows GUI automation working with a specific window regardless of its state

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, mouseclick-event

I am working on a project written in Python that should perform some actions in an opened application window. For example I run application window with 3 buttons at 3 different positions. I write a script using `auto-gui` lib for **python 3** and set `x, y` coordinates to click on 3 button positions. But my problem is: If I minimize this window, clicker clicks at the given position within another currently open window.

My main question: is there a way (with help of a lib or by any other means) to trigger or bind this script to work only with this opened (or specified) application. And if I minimize this window, clicker continues to work in this minimized window, not in the currently active one. Please suggest.

Comment: Not a Windows person myself, but colleagues inflicted with it were using https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto IIRC. Perhaps it helps you?

Comment: @OndrejK. Thanks for your reply! Interesting one! I will test it and inform you back!

Comment: What I remember is that you could navigate controls hierarchy to select what you take your action on (so not just define coords), but I do not know if it can bind to a window (and work even when minimized), that goes well beyond my understanding of Windows GUI scripting. ;)

Comment: I type for example minimized, the clicker should works on one application window and if you open another aplication , clicker continue works on first one , not on new opened:)

Comment: If I understood you correctly... you want the actions to be performed on that one application/window you have specified. Regardless of its state. Even when minimized. This also presumably means something (or someone else) can be interacting with the machines Windows GUI while this script keeps clicking (activating) controls in that one window it was assigned to. Right?

Comment: absolutely right!!!

Comment: Is is possible? Because i do some research and can’t found usefull information about it

Comment: Apart from suggesting to check out the pywinauto, someone else with more insights need to pick that up. I would doubt registering as click (since that would suggest two sources of mouse events (user and scripts) fighting for attention, but really not a Windows GUI programmer)... but perhaps by using corresponding API, it may be possible. Find the control element (button) and trigger its mouse click event.

Comment: you can use phantom js which helps to test in ghost mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `win32gui` module, more specifically to `SetActiveWindows, SetForegroundWindow, SetActiveWindows` also `EnumWindows` to find your application.
With these you can detect a certain application by it's title using `EnumWindows` you can then maximize it and set it as active so it will be fullscreen and the first one you see on the monitor. This way you can now use the (x,y) coordinates for clicks because the windows will always be maximized therefore the buttons in the same position everytime.